# python pandas add new calculated column by evaluating expressions(combination of other columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, expression, calculated-columns

I am new to pandas, data-frames  i am struggling at a point where i 
need to add a new column to my data frame which is something like 
combination of other columns on the basis of arithmetic operations 
something like..

```
Dataframe columns:
col1 , col2 col3.. etc

Functions:
sum() 
count()
distinct()
min()
etc..

Operators: like + - * / etc..

now user can drag and drop anything from above 3(functions, columns 
and operators) which might make expression like..

sum(col1) + min(col2) * 10 + 2    or something like this...
```

So my question how can i calculate it on pandas dataframe which forms 
(calculated) a new column in dataframe.

Please help me, how can i implement this feature where i can give 
permission to user to choose any combination of column and operation 
or combination of operation on a single column which i call as 
calculated column

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why my question marked as -1 but i finally find out the answer,
just i need to modify the expression being created via drag and drop and user this function from python's **eval()** which nicely works with pandas data-frames

```
df.eval(col1.sum() + col2.min() * 10 + 2)
```

and it works fine for any expression, hope it helps anyone similar.